# Why is that Python 3 IDE in some sites doesn't support f string function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

f string function

```
print(f"{theString}")
```

makes it easier to print the string than this

```
print("{}".format(theString))
```

But Python 3 compiler in certain sites doesn't support this function. Is there some specific version of Python for this function to support this.

Edit: Hackerrank.com like some other sites just mention it as Python 3 or 2 and no specific version

[image]

Comment: it should work for version >= 3.6

Comment: [This is the PEP that indtroduced f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?)  Note that "Python-Version" is 3.6

Comment: A Google search for "python f string" would have taken you to [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) as the first hit, which states the python version it applies to.

Comment: FYI, you can check the version with `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: Why was it downvoted into oblivion? :o

Comment: @AK47 That's what stackoverflow people do.

Comment: @abhijithvijayan not all of them ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python 3.6 introduced f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?). Any python version 3.6 or higher will support this feature.

Comment: [image](https://i.imgur.com/rnuUHNb.png) Maybe the site is using a version less than 3.6 then.

Comment: @abhijithvijayan yes definitely! That is what everyone is saying ;)